# Android ViewFlipper Inside ScrollView

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am using view flipper to show bunch on images like a slider where i implemented the functionality of swipe left and right to switch images, now some of my images are larger than the screen size ( in terms of height ) are getting hidden.

I thought of adding my ViewFlipper inside ScrollView but using that i am not able to use the swipe functionality here goes my code

XML LAYOUT

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/mover"
android:fillViewport="true">

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
    </ViewFlipper>
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
ScrollView moverHandle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int gallery_grid_Images[]={R.drawable.itema,R.drawable.itemb,
            R.drawable.itemc,R.drawable.itemd,
            R.drawable.iteme,R.drawable.itemf,
            R.drawable.itemg,R.drawable.itemh,
            R.drawable.itemi,R.drawable.itemj,
    };
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
     for(int i=0;i<gallery_grid_Images.length;i++)
     {
        //  This will create dynamic image view and add them to ViewFlipper
            setFlipperImage(gallery_grid_Images[i]);
     }
     moverHandle = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.mover);
     moverHandle.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
         public void onSwipeRight() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            } 
         public void onSwipeLeft() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            } 
     });
}

private void setFlipperImage(int res) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    image.setBackgroundResource(res);
    viewFlipper.addView(image);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

FINALLY HERE GOES MY TOUCH LISTENER

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

View view;
MotionEvent motionEvent;

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried implementing onTouchIntercept?

Comment: no , i have no idea how to do that

Comment: Aman, could you get any solution? I too am facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code as in link below
http://techin-android.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/swipe-event-in-android-scrollview.html#!/2011/11/swipe-event-in-android-scrollview.html
Overriding the onTouch event of Gesture seems to be the culprit.